# spring testing @async method

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-java-config, spring-aspects

I'm trying to test if `@Async` annotation of Spring is working as expected on my project. But It doesn't.

I have this test:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = GlobalConfiguration.class)
    public class ActivityMessageListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ActivityMessageListener activityMessageListener;

    private Long USER_ID = 1l;
    private Long COMPANY_ID = 2l;
    private Date DATE = new Date(10000000);
    private String CLASSNAME = "className";
    private Long CLASSPK = 14l;
    private Integer TYPE = 22;
    private String EXTRA_DATA = "extra";
    private Long RECIVED_USER_ID = 99l;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoReceiveWithException() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Current thread " +      Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap();
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_USER_ID, USER_ID);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_COMPANY_ID, COMPANY_ID);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CREATE_DATE, DATE);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CLASS_NAME, CLASSNAME);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CLASS_PK, CLASSPK);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_TYPE, TYPE);
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_EXTRA_DATA, EXTRA_DATA );
        values.put(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_RECEIVED_USER_ID, RECIVED_USER_ID);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setValues(values);
        MessageBusUtil.sendMessage(MKTDestinationNames.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY,      message);

    }
}
```

As you can see I'm printing the name of the current thread.
The class containing the `@Async` method is:

```
 public class ActivityMessageListener extends BaseMessageListener {

    public static final String PARAM_USER_ID                = "userId";
    public static final String PARAM_COMPANY_ID             = "companyId";
    public static final String PARAM_CREATE_DATE            = "createDate";
    public static final String PARAM_CLASS_NAME             = "className";
    public static final String PARAM_CLASS_PK               = "classPK";
    public static final String PARAM_TYPE                   = "type";
    public static final String PARAM_EXTRA_DATA             = "extraData";
    public static final String PARAM_RECEIVED_USER_ID       = "receiverUserId";

    public ActivityMessageListener() {
        MessageBusUtil.addQueue(MKTDestinationNames.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY, this);
    }

    @Override
    @Async(value = "activityExecutor")
    public void doReceive(Message message) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Current " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        if (1> 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("lalal");
        Map<String, Object> parameters  = message.getValues();
        Long userId                     = (Long)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_USER_ID);
        Long companyId                  = (Long)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_COMPANY_ID);
        Date createDate                 = (Date)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CREATE_DATE);
        String className                = (String)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CLASS_NAME);
        Long classPK                    = (Long)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_CLASS_PK);
        Integer type                    = (Integer)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_TYPE);
        String extraData                = (String)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_EXTRA_DATA);
        Long receiverUserId             = (Long)parameters.get(ActivityMessageListener.PARAM_RECEIVED_USER_ID);
        ActivityLocalServiceUtil.addActivity(userId, companyId, createDate, className, classPK, type, extraData, receiverUserId);
    }

}
```

Here I'm printing the name of the current thread inside of the `@Async` method, and the name is the same as before, main. So it's not working.

The GlobalConfiguration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({
        "com.shn.configurations",
...some packages...
})
public class GlobalConfiguration {...}
```

And inside one of the specified packages has the activityExecutor bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ExecutorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ActivityMessageListener activityMessageListener() {
        return new ActivityMessageListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor activityExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = 
        new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);

        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For my own curiosity, did `MessageBusUtil.addQueue` do what I assumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky.

Asynchronous behavior is added through proxying.

Spring provides you with a proxy that wraps the actual object and performs the actual invocation in a separate thread.

It looks something like this (except most of this is done dynamically with CGLIB or JDK proxies and Spring handlers)

```
class ProxyListener extends ActivityMessageListener {
    private ActivityMessageListener real;
    public ProxyListener(ActivityMessageListener real) {
        this.real = real;
    }
    TaskExecutor executor; // injected
    @Override
    public void doReceive(Message message) throws Exception {
        executor.submit(() -> real.doReceive(message)); // in another thread
    }
}

ActivityMessageListener real = new ActivityMessageListener();
ProxyListener proxy = new ProxyListener(real);
```

Now, in a Spring world, you'd have a reference to the `proxy` object, not to the `ActivityMessageListener`. That is

```
ActivityMessageListener proxy = applicationContext.getBean(ActivityMessageListener.class);
```

would return a reference to the `ProxyListener`. Then, through polymorphism, invoking `doReceive` would go to the overriden `Proxy#doReceive` method which would invoke `ActivityMessageListener#doReceive` through delegation and you'd get your asynchronous behavior.

However, you're in a half Spring world.

Here

```
public ActivityMessageListener() {
    MessageBusUtil.addQueue(MKTDestinationNames.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY, this);
}
```

the reference `this` is actually referring to the real `ActivityMessageListener`, not to the proxy. So when, presumably, you send your message on the bus here

```
MessageBusUtil.sendMessage(MKTDestinationNames.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY,      message);
```

you're sending it to the real object, which doesn't have the proxy asynchronous behavior.

The full Spring solution would be to have the MessabeBus (and/or its queue) be Spring beans in which you can inject the fully process (proxied, autowired, initialized) beans.

---

In reality, since CGLIB proxies are really just subclasses of your types, so the `ProxyListener` above would actually also add itself to the bus since the `super` constructor would be invoked. It would seem though that only one `MessageListener` can register itself with a key, like `MKTDestinationNames.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY`. If this isn't the case, you'd have to show more of that code for explanation.

---

In your test, if you do

```
activityMessageListener.doReceive(message);
```

you should see that asynchronous behavior since `activityMessageListener` should hold a reference to the proxy.